# Category name in page title

Tags: categories

All I'm trying to do is put the category title on a category listing page into the title tag.
So I've got the variable set up, but if I add the category title tag:

```
{% set title = "{{ category.title }}" %}
```

The end result is this

```
<title>{{ category.title}}</title>
```

So do I need to escape the quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to fill in the quote's or the curly brackets.

You could just put it down like this:

```
{% set title = category.title %}
```

You already "called" twig so you dont need to do that again.